# Individual Data point size within a dataset for finetuning for translation

Tags: fine-tuning, training-datasets, machine-translation

I need to fine tuning a LLM for a translation task for specific domain. Could someone please advise if length of each data point within the data set has any impact on eventual performance of the LLMs. which approach is better - using data of longer length (e.g. large sentences , say closer to context length) or using shorter length data points (smaller sentences). The former is easier for me, while the later seems more intuitive.

TIA.